# ¿Cómo puedo generar una clave API para mi cuenta personal en la cuenta de servicio y acceder a los datos de Google Analytics de mi aplicación?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics

He creado una cuenta para poder crear claves de API de Google Analytics para acceder a los datos de Google Analytics de mi sitio web utilizando la API con [un Script de Python](https://github.com/tanyazyabkina/GoogleAnalyticsReportingAPI_python/blob/main/Google%20Analytics%20Reporting%20API%20GitHub.ipynb).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, no puedo añadirlo a Google Analytics porque no tengo los derechos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo generar una clave API para mi cuenta personal en la cuenta de servicio y acceder a los datos de Google Analytics de mi aplicación? Efectivamente, parece que no puedo añadir mi propia cuenta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El Administrador de la cuenta en Google Cloud tiene que darle permiso al usuario que quiere crear la cuenta de servicio. El mensaje de error es bastante claro.

Comment: Entonces, ¿no puedo crear una cuenta con mi correo electrónico antoine@mycompany.com que tenga acceso a Google Analytics desde MyCompany, 
@A.Cedano ?

Comment: Si tienes contratado Google Workspace sí, de lo contrario tendrás que crear el proyecto desde una cuenta de Google y autorizar a la cuenta de correo que refieres (esto último no lo he comprobado). Aunque no veo qué sentido tenga hacer eso, lo importante es que autorices tu dominio para que pueda acceder a los proyectos que crees bajo tu cuenta de Cloud Platform

Comment: He creado el proyecto desde una cuenta de Google Suite Workspace (antoine[at]mycompany.com) @A.Cedano per no sé como autorizar la cuenta de correo que refiero (no sé como hacer eso en el lado Google Console). Ejecuto mi script en un cuaderno de google colaboratory

Comment: ¿La cuenta que quieres autorizar es otra distinta de `antoine@mycompany.com`? ¿El dominio de dicha cuenta es el mismo, o sea `mycompany.com`? ¿Esa cuenta está dada de alta en Workspace?

Comment: Bueno, como no puedo integrar la que termina con [at]vividoutcome en Google Analytics quiero utilisar [at]mycompany, de Workspace porque es lo qué utiliso en Google Analytics @A.Cedano

Comment: Puedes configurar el proyecto de Google Cloud Console con la cuenta con la que tengas acceso al entorno Google (cualquiera que sea). Lo importante es que en el dominio donde vas a usar la API dispongas de la clave de API o archivo que te prorporciona Google al crear el proyecto y que autorices el dominio a trabajar con ese proyecto.